# Update an element that already has a plugin

Tags: zurb-foundation

Zurb Foundation 6.5.3

I have an accordion menu which needs to be updated via ajax after the initial page load. So initially the menu contains 2 items, then `$(document).foundation();` is called. Later after an ajax response is received elements are added (and potentially removed/replaced) within the menu.

I would like to be able to re-use the same elements however, I can't update the plugin to re-style the changed elements. I've tried:

1. `$("#my-menu").foundation();` which doesn't work and shows the error:

   > Tried to initialize accordion-menu on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.
2. `Foundation.reflow(menu, 'accordion');` which doesn't work.
3. `menu.foundation('reflow');` which doesn't work and shows the error:

   > Uncaught ReferenceError: We're sorry, 'reflow' is not an available method for AccordionMenu.

---

I have made it work by destroying and removing the existing menu, re-creating the whole thing, then calling `$("#my-menu").foundation();` however this isn't ideal in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that my issue was due to no one solution working in all 3 cases:

1. foundation has not yet been initialised
2. foundation is initialised and the entire element has been replaced since
3. foundation is initialised and the element has been updated since

Unless someone has a better answer, I solved using this approach:

```
// this can happen before, or after code creates the menu
$(document).foundation();
console.log("foundation run");
__foundationRun = true;


...


function foundationUpdate(el) {
    if (__foundationRun) {
        if (el.data('zfPlugin'))
            // already initialised, update it
            Foundation.reInit(el);
        else
            // new element, initialise it
            el.foundation();
    }
    // else leave for foundation initialise
}

....

// ... do updates (modify or replace entirely) and then:
foundationUpdate($("#my-menu"));
```

Comment: Nice solution ! I've encountered same issue as you, your approach helped me a lot !! Thanks. I tried many solution to re initialize an accordion menu without success;